# What is f4texRECT?

Tags: unity-game-engine, cg

I'm reviewing a code and I see this function:

```
void f4texRECTneighbors(samplerRECT tex, float2 s, out float4 left
, out float4 right, out float4 top, out float4 bottom)
{
  left   = f4texRECT(tex, s - float2(1, 0)); 
  right  = f4texRECT(tex, s + float2(1, 0));
  bottom = f4texRECT(tex, s + float2(0, 1));
  top    = f4texRECT(tex, s - float2(0, 1));
}
```

I have two questions:

1. What is f4texRECT exactly?
2. When I use it in unity it complains with **undeclared identifier 'f4texRECT'**. What is its equivalent in unity?

Comment: If you are a Cg programmer you should know that f4texRECT samples the texture to a float4.

Comment: Then what is the difference with  tex2D?

Comment: tex2D() is for HLSL and its equivalent for Cg is F4textRECT. However right now I can't remember the other method for Cg...